# Remove all files in folder (non-recursive) in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, how can I delete all the files in a folder, but without deleting folders or going into the subfolders? Nothing fancy, just an equivalent to `del C:\Path\To\Folder\*.*`

**Edit:** I don't want to exclude any files. Actually nevermind, I found out that what I was looking for is `Remove-Item C:\Path\To\Folder\*.*`

Comment: `help -full Remove-Item`

Comment: @Jelphy That one is for recursive and it excludes files, I don't want to exclude files and I don't want it to be recursive.

Comment: @sashoalm Please post some code or show an attempt so that the community can answer this. It's trivial.

Comment: @sashoalm The post mentions excluding _folders_ not files. Just use `Remove-Item` and don't specify the `-Recurse` switch: - `Remove-Item * -Exclude dir1, dir2`

Comment: @Jelphy This is not a good solution - it should be automatic, you shouldn't need to exlude everything you do not want to delete.

Comment: @Jelphy Thanks, that's what I needed. I have a powershell script in my Jenkins build server written by someone else, and aside from that simple command I don't need anything else. I have zero knowledge of PowerShell and I'm dealing with it only because I have to edit an existing script.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have PowerShell v3 or newer you could do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\path\to\folder' -File | Remove-Item -Force
```

Prior to PowerShell v3 you need to filter the `Get-ChildItem` output for items that aren't containers (i.e. directories) in order to get just files:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\path\to\folder' | Where-Object {
  -not $_.PSIsContainer
} | Remove-Item -Force
```